# Lift ReplaceOptions causes select to lose action

Tags: scala, lift

I make this call to set up a select with a handler:

```
val options:List[(String,String)] = List(("1","test"),("2","test2")) 
"#drugSelect" #> ajaxSelect(drugOptions, Empty, handler)
```

At this point I can select something in the list and the handler gets called. Later on, I make this call to replace the options. The options get replaced just fine.

```
val options:List[(String,String)] = List(("3","test"),("4","test2"))
ReplaceOptions("drugSelect", options, Empty)
```

However, once I call ReplaceOptions, the callback to the handler no longer occurs when I select in the select field. The html looks like this:

```
<div data-lift="marketplace.AutoComplete.getNames">
     <input id="drugSearch" type="text" class="input-large">
     <div>
         <label for="drugSelect">Select Drug:</label>
         <select id="drugSelect"></select>
     </div>
     <div id="drugMessage">Messages</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying reason this happens is that Lift option rendering generates a one-time value for each option that maps back to your server-side value. So when you `ReplaceOptions`, you lose those unique values and the server can no longer make sense of the submitted content.

The solution here is to use `ajaxUntrustedSelect`. It pipes the values in your collection directly to the HTML, and allows them to be submitted as-is. It also doesn't filter callbacks to ensure that the submitted options were in your original list. This is slightly less secure, but allows you to use `ReplaceOptions` as you're doing above.

The other possibility is to use an `idMemoize` around the container of the `select` element, and re-render the `idMemoize` when you need to update the select options.